# jquery comma css change

Tags: jquery, css, tags

This is a tough question, and I'll do my best to describe it.

I have an text input where users can enter in tags.

After a user types a tag in the input (such as "starcraft") and presses the comma key, I want all characters before the comma (i.e. the word starcraft) to change color and background color.  Thus after a user types a tag and presses comma, he can see the word in a tag form.

How would I do this using jquery?

Comment: Does it have to be using jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge, there's no easy way to modify the style of just part of the text in a textbox. However, you could do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<span id="tags"></span><input id="enterTag" type="text" />
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$('#enterTag').keydown(function(event) {
    var tag = $(this).val();
    // 188 is comma, 13 is enter
    if (event.which === 188 || event.which === 13) {
        if (tag) {
            $('#tags').append('<span>' + tag + '</span>');
            $(this).val('');
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    // 8 is backspace
    else if (event.which == 8) {
        if (!tag) {
            $('#tags span:last').remove();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
#tags span {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #6999c0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 4px;
    border: solid 1px #477eab;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/xckjk/

Comment: Where could I find a list of (no name) 188->comma,13->enter,... ?

Comment: Search for "JavaScript key codes". This is the page that I used: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/javascript-char-codes-key-codes.aspx

Comment: Excellent! I was just fiddling this too, but just the layout, hadn't tackled the JS - http://jsfiddle.net/kRXVV/1/  I push the tag spans *into* the `<input ..>` and adjust its left margin to force the cursor past the existing tags. Those offsets would all have to be calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `contentEditable` `div` for this.  You cannot style chunks of text within a regular `input`.  You will want to create a `contentEditable` `div`, and then run code on keypress (or keydown) which will wrap the text in a span which is then styled.

Comment: how do i wrap text in span just in front of comma on keypress?

Comment: @zzzzBov how's that?  I didn't think you could style text in a textarea.

Comment: @kingjiv, i take that back. I must have misremembered my experimentation with a customized textarea. I probably had replaced a `textarea` using a `div[contenteditable]`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible just using input textbox. You will have to use a combination of div/span and input textbox. On keypress event you have to dynamically create the required tags and append in the div.

Answer (score 0):

Textboxes can't do this. You can take a few approaches:

1) set focus to a hidden input box and listen to key events. Then simulate a textbox and the behaviour you describe using DIVs, SPANs and CSS.

2) Show the highlighted terms (or tags) below the textbox (easier)

3) Use the technique kingjiv suggests

In either case this is not a simple task.